# Did Perot "spoil" some state results?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

In 1992, Bill Clinton won some states many did not expect him to win and Democrats never won for president since, though Obama came close in 2008 to some including Montana. For example, Bill Clinton won Montana even though the state normally votes Republican on the presidential level. The same happened with Louisiana. I have heard that Perot contributed to Bush's electoral win. Even though Perot won some counties, he got no electoral votes. I am asking about the states and ho Perot's unusually successful candidacy swung states.

Note: I think the same factor that made a blue Montana in 1992 made a red Michigan in 2016.

Comment: Not exactly, I am asking about state level results. It is pretty close though.

Comment: Isn't that the same? You can't swing the election without swinging states, so any answer to that question should answer this one

Comment: You can swing states without swinging the election, so if the answer to the other question is "no", (which it appears to be) it does *not* answer this question.